# android get value from Json object

Tags: android, json, key-value

I am scanning a bar code which returns a result in a Json format from a barcode api.

The scan method is returning a bar code number which uses a Volley request to get the appropriate items Json data.  That seems to work correctly as the result in a jsonObject is:

```
{"valid":"true",
"number":"021500058506",
"itemname":"Lawry&#39;s Garlic Salt Coarse Ground W\/Parsley",
"alias":"",
"description":"",
"avg_price":"",
"rate_up":0,
"rate_down":0}
```

The problem lies in the extraction of the value for "itemname". With the following code I get an empty result for the String textResult.

```
public void findProduct(){

    final JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
        (Request.Method.GET, getUrl(), null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                String textResult = "";
                try {
                    JSONObject productItem = response.getJSONObject("");

                    textResult = productItem.getString("itemname");

                    } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                contentTxt.setText(textResult);

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Text Result" + textResult, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if(error != null) Log.e("MainActivity", error.getMessage());

            }
        });

    VolleyHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
}
```

Any idea why:

```
textResult = productItem.getString("itemname");
```

is not giving me the value of "itemname"?

Thanks

Comment: `JSONObject productItem = response.getJSONObject("");` Is the problem I guess. Is `productItem ` filled properly?

Comment: Are you getting an error message? If yes, also put this in the question.

Comment: @ eyeballz - yes, I know the response is the jsonobject in the text above.  The object comes through ok with getJSONObject("") as it is a single item with no name.  At least that is what I'm thinking.  I usually get in trouble thinking though.

Comment: @ eyeballz - No error just the blank value assigned earlier.

Comment: try `textResult = response.getString("itemname")`

Comment: @eyeballz - getting the same result...or lack there of.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91420/discussion-between-bkane56-and-eyeballz).

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
JSONObject productItem = response.getJSONObject("");
```

Need to be:

```
JSONObject productItem = new JSONObject(YOUR_JSON_STRING);
```